# What do 2[p] and 6[p] mean?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
   char c[]="GATECSIT2017";
   char *p=c;
   printf("%s", c+2[p]-6[p]-1);
   return 0;
}
```

What do `2[p]` and `6[p]` mean?
Please provide a detailed explanation.

Output: `17`

Comment: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/joke.html

Comment: `2[p]` is same as `p[2]`, `6[p]` is same as `p[6]`

So p[2] = 'T' and p[6] = 'I' i.e `c + 84 - 73 -1` i.e. c+10. ( Substituting ASCII values of characters

`c[10]` is pointing to `1` in the string. When we print it as string beginning from 10th index, the output will be 17

Answer (score 4):

For any valid pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is equal to `*(p + i)`. And due to the [commutative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) of addition `*(p + i)` is equal to `*(i + p)` which is then equal to `i[p]`.

In short, `2[p]` is the same as `p[2]`.

Answer (score 2):

> What do `2[p]` and `6[p]` mean?

`2[p]` is equivalent to `p[2]` and `6[p]` is equivalent to `p[6]`.